# Como criar funções com callback?

Tags: jquery

Alguém sabe me dizer como criar funções com callback?
Eu Criei essa função mas não está funcionando.

```
        function PostsCategoriasListar(table, select, callback) {
        if (table) {
            $.ajax({
                url: controller_dashboard,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {acao: 'PostsCategoriasListar', Listar: 'table'},
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'LogOff') {
                        window.setTimeout(function() {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }, 10000);
                    }
                    $element.find('table tbody').html(response.table);
                    ExecuteDataTable(0, maximo, 1);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
        if (select) {
            $.ajax({
                url: controller_dashboard,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {acao: 'PostsCategoriasListar', Listar: 'select'},
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'LogOff') {
                        window.setTimeout(function() {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }, 10000);
                    }
                    $element.find('form select').html(response.select);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
        //EU QUERO QUE O CALLBACK SO EXECULTE DEPOIS QUE TODO CODIGO QUE ESTIVER NOS IF'S ACIMA TENHAN TERMINADO, ELE SEMPRE EXECULTA ANTES ONDE ESTOU ERRANDO?
        if (typeof callback === 'function')
            callback();
    }
```

PS: eu não coloquei as requisições ajax pois iria deixar muito grande sendo que elas estão funcionando só que preciso que elas executem primeiro e depois que terminarem seja executado o callback

Comment: Coloque a chamada a `callback()` dentro do próprio `success`. Como chamadas Ajax são assíncronas (por padrão), se você colocar fora ela será chamada antes mesmo do Ajax começar. Não há problema em se referir a uma variável da função dentro de outra função mais interna (i.e. *closure*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa chamar o `callback` quando receber a resposta da requisição ajax. Note que na sua lógica pode ser que duas requisições ajax sejam feitas (`if (table)` e `if (select)`). O código abaixo assume que isso **não é o caso**, então coquei o `if select` no else do primeiro if.

```
function PostsCategoriasListar(table, select, callback) {
    if (table) {
        $.ajax({
            url: controller_dashboard,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {acao: 'PostsCategoriasListar', Listar: 'table'},
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'LogOff') {
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }, 10000);
                } else {
                    $element.find('table tbody').html(response.table);
                    ExecuteDataTable(0, maximo, 1);
                    callback();
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                callback(error);
            }
        });
    } else if (select) {
        $.ajax({
            url: controller_dashboard,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {acao: 'PostsCategoriasListar', Listar: 'select'},
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'LogOff') {
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }, 10000);
                } else {
                    $element.find('form select').html(response.select);
                    callback();
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                callback(error);
            }
        });
    } else {
        callback('Ou table ou select precisam ter um valor');
    }
}
```

Mais uma sugestão: chame o callback mesmo no caso do erro (passando o erro como parâmetro). Nesse caso, quem chamou a função `PostsCategoriasListar` pode saber se ocorreu um erro ou não:

```
PostsCategoriasListar(function(error) {
    if (!error) {
         // executado com sucesso
    } else {
        // houve um erro na chamada
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado não era exatamente isso que precisava pois nessa função as vezes necessito executar as requisições Ajax dos 2 "if" porem sua resposta me deu uma luz de como fazer, já fiz aqui e funcionou muito bem. muito obrigado.